# iOS safari: (-webkit-)box-shadow on input:focus doesn't work

Tags: css, webkit, mobile-webkit

Safari has some strange behavior towards `box-shadow`.

```
input[type="text"]{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000000;
}
input[type="text"]:focus{
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #ffffff;
}
```

The `box-shadow` is displayed but as soon as the element gets focus the shadow vanishes completely. Same effect happens if you don't set anything in :focus.

It does work on Desktop-Safari. I'm using iOS 5 beta (iPad), I can't test it on a stable release or other devices.

Does anyone has a solution to this?

Comment: Closely related: [iPhone iOS will not display box-shadow properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757146/iphone-ios-will-not-display-box-shadow-properly)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use -webkit-appearance: none to override the native look:

```
input[type="text"]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000000;
}
```

Comment: Nope that was just an example. Any way the shadow is not displayed when the input is focused.

Comment: The box shadow shows, but the input is gone.  Safari the new IE.

Comment: `-webkit-appearance: none;` working perfect